# Conditional expectation with coins

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

We have $X_n=1$ if it's heads (T) on the $n$-toss and $X_n=0$ otherwise ($n=1,...$). We also have $T_1=$ number of coin tosses needed to observe the first T and $T_2=$ total number of coin tosses to observe the second T. Find $\mathbb{E}[T_2|T_1]$.

I've found the joint law that is $\mathbb{P}(T_1=k,T_2=n)=\mathbb{P}(T_1=k)\mathbb{P}(T_2=n|T_1=k)=\frac{1}{2^n}$, but now I'm stuck.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the tosses are all independent, $E[T_2\,|\,T_1]=T_1+E[T_1]$.

Comment: Note:  Your formula $P(T_1=k\cap T_2=n)=\frac 1{2^n}$ is not complete.  If $k≥n$ then the answer is $0$

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your answer. For your note, I say that $\forall k<n$.

Comment: I don't see where that condition appears in your post, but I agree that would suffice.

Comment: @lulu Could you explain me how you obtained $T_1+E[T_1]$?

Comment: If you are waiting to see the second $T$, you first wait to see the first one..in your set up, we are told that this takes $T_1$ tosses.  But as soon as you see that first one, the game effectively resets and you are now just waiting to see that first one again, which we know is expected to take $E[T_1]=2$ steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression $E(T_2 | T_1)$, $T_1$ is no longer a random variable.  Therefore, the question reduces to "if I've already observed one head after $T_1$ flips, how many more flips should I expect for the second head?"  Or, phrased differently, how many flips until I see a head?  Thus,
\begin{equation*}
E(T_2 | T_1) = T_1 + E(Y)
\end{equation*}

where $Y$ is the number of flips I need to wait to see a head.  As lulu mentioned in the comments, finding $E(Y)$ is the same problem as finding $E(T_1)$.  Hence,
\begin{equation*}
E(T_2 | T_1) = T_1 + E(T_1) = T_1 + 2
\end{equation*}

Personally, I prefer to introduce the new notation, $Y$, to make it clear there is a step in between the final statement.  The notation is a bit tricky here, as $T_1$ is not a random quantity in the term $E(T_2 | T_1)$.  Others may cringe at introducing more notation.

It's helpful to note that the answer to $E(X|Y)$ will always be written in terms of $Y$ (assuming we aren't dealing with degenerate random variables).